# Rails separate array items with comma inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

What is the most elegant way in Rails to create a comma-separated list inside a partial?

I've just recently discovered that you can use partials to iterate through a collection sent from another view template. So in the view template I have:

```
<% render @dvd.director %>
```

Then in /view/directors/_director.html.erb:

```
<%= director.director %>
```

This actually does something like:

```
@dvd.director.each { |d| puts d.director }
```

Now, I know I could use a .join like so:

```
<% @dvd.director.map { |t| t.director }.join(", ") %>
```

But since the partial already iterates through each entry in the array, how can I separate the lists properly and not have the last one (or a single one) with an ugly comma at the end?

A lot of entries will have only one director, I just want to separate those that have more than one properly. I know I can do all this manually (using a normal, non-iterating partial and creating the .each loop myself), but am trying to do it, and learn, the Rails way.

Thanks.

**Edit**

To try to explain a little better, @dvd.director returns an ActiveRelation object like so:

```
[#<Director id: 13, director: "Andrew Stanton">, #<Director id: 14, director: "Lee Unkrich">]
```

So I can't just do `@dvd.director.join(', ')`

Is there another way to get that data other than

```
@dvd.director.each { |dir| dir.director }
```

Because there I have the same problem, I have to count them or make sure it's not the last item before I put a comma between them, or extract just the director names and put them into a string or something like that. If I could do a join it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's `join` method won't add the separator character if there is only a single element in the array.

You should be able to do the following for a list of any size:

```
@dvd.director.map(&:director).join(", ")
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a link_to in that file if I'm already using `map(&:director)`?

Comment: Try something like this:
`= dvd.directors.map {|director| link_to director.name, dvd_director_path(dvd,director)}.join(", ").html_safe`